# How can i append the username (principal) to each log line in Wildfly?

Tags: wildfly, wildfly-10, jboss-logging

I am working with Wildfly 10 and I am using its logging subsystem.

Now, I need to append the LoginName of the currently logged in User (principal) from the session to every log message that is processed by the JBoss Logging Subsystem.

Is there a generic way to do this, rather than appending the UserName to every Log Message in my Application?

For example i could do:

```
        HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest)externalContext.getRequest();
        UserModel user = (UserModel)request.getSession().getAttribute("user");
        String username = user.getName();
```

But how can i get the Logging Subsystem to do this for every Log Message?

Comment: You'd either have to append the user or use something like `MDC` (depending on your logging framework). Logging itself doesn't have any knowledge of the user.

Comment: Thanx a lot for your answer. My best idea is now to create a Wildfly module which implements a custom log handler that references the current session. Would that be possible? I am having a hard time to figure out how to build and deploy a cusom wildfly module. I would appreciate if someone could point me in the right direction.

Comment: It wouldn't work as logging doesn't know what a session is. You may be able to use a servlet listener which would insert the user in MDC, then remove it when the request is complete.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As James R. Perkins suggested, this can be done be using MDC (Mapped Diagnostic Context).

An example of how this works can be found here: 
https://veerasundar.com/blog/2009/11/log4j-mdc-mapped-diagnostic-context-example-code/

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same situation as yours and found that there is no Wildfly in built support for the same.
Hence the two options that you can have are-

1. Append username to the logs manually as what you mentioned already in your question. Personally I prefer this to keep the logging minimum and relevant.
2. Use [MDC](https://www.baeldung.com/mdc-in-log4j-2-logback) and along with that implement 'filter' attribute of logging in Wildfly, so that you can keep only relevant log messages in your log file.